# Is it possible using an external hard drive to run Pop! Os with 200gb allocated, and the rest allocated to windows as a normal external drive?

Tags: linux

I've been wanting to run Pop! Os from an external hard drive, but I also want to be able to use the rest as a normal usb drive. Is this possible to do? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You may find an answer more quickly by checking with the Pop!_OS specialists at http://pop.system76.com/docs , http://reddit.com/r/pop_os , or in http://chat.pop-os.org but this question is certainly a good one and may be asked and answered here. 1) Does your PC support UEFI? 2) Does the external drive attach by USB, FireWire, or external SATA? Please click [edit] to add that important info to the question so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about the system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

1) [Install Pop!_OS](https://github.com/pop-os/docs/blob/master/docs/install-pop-os.md) from its LiveUSb or LiveDVD media. Your PC needs to have 64-bit x86 architecture. Two (2) GB of RAM is required, four (4) GB of RAM is recommended; 20 GB of storage is recommended.

2) Choose a custom installation.

[image: Screenshot showing where to pick Custom Installation]

3) When it asks where to install to, specify the external drive. Does it see the drive? Good!

4) Leave 200 GB free at the end of the drive for Windows use.

5) After completing the installation, reboot into windows, and use [Drive Manager](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080) to partition and format the remaining 200 GB of space for NTFS (Basic) use.